# Не получается изменить пароль пользователя в Django

Tags: python, django

Я делаю простую регистрацию пользователя на Django. Регистрация и вход пользователя работает. Теперь я хочу чтоб пользователь мог зайти к себе в профиль и смог изменить свой пароль. Для этого я воспользовался PasswordChangeForm. И вот что я делаю. Файл views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
class ChangeFormView(FormView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = '/'
    template_name = 'app/edit_pass.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    return super(ChangeFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

файд urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
# некоторые урлы здесь
url(r'^edit_pass/$', views.ChangeFormView.as_view()),
]
```

в файле profile.html я прописываю ссылку для изменения пароля

```
<a href="/edit_pass">change a password</a>
```

В файле edit_pass.html у меня простая форма

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">edit a password</button>
</form>
```

По итогу я получаю ошибку TypeError at /edit_pass/
 Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл views.py

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
class ChangeFormView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    template_name = 'app/edit_pass.html'
    success_url = '/index'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ChangeFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = kwargs.pop('instance')
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Примите свой ответ